# Online .NET IDE?

Tags: .net, ide

Does anyone know of a (free?) web-based IDE for .NET development online?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does it need to be web-based?

Comment: because you're on vacation and you don't want to install vs on your friend's laptop, and you want to test somtn that blows up your geeky mind

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's [CodeRun](http://coderun.com/) for ASP.NET/PHP/Ajax apps.

Comment: Amazing, my mind is blown.

Comment: But it doesn't have IntelliSense (or is it just me?)

Comment: @JohnB: It seems to have at least some level of IntelliSense. I get a nice pop-up panel thingy with method names and whatnot just like in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

You can find some usefull features at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Compilr](http://www.compilr.com/), it allows C#, VB, Java.  Full disclosure, I'm one of the founders.

Comment: It's not free dude, I said I am looking for a free one.

Comment: Yes, it's free you just don't get any private projects.  Just visit http://compilr.com/user/register

Comment: The free account has been removed by now. You have to sign up and get a 14 day free trial.

Comment: It's also dead now (well it's been integrated into lynda.com in some form or shape)