# Is software development in the cloud practical?

Tags: cloud, development-environment

Has anyone tried software development in the cloud? Rather than set up a desktop or laptop computer with a web server, DBMS, compiler and IDE, I'm thinking about installing these on an Amazon EC2 instance. Then I could connect to it via a VNC client and do development from anywhere that I have Internet access. But I'm concerned about speed and security. If you've considered or tried this, please share your thoughts.

Comment: As fast as connecting to any other remote server.  Amazon knows more about security than I do.  I think it's a great, low cost environment.

Comment: Mildly related (though .NET-specific): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2422035/60462. We will probably see more browser-based IDEs in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a complete Development environment on the cloud. However, you should choose between an IaaS or a PaaS for your purpose. On a PaaS, you usually enable the services that you want and you start using them without taking care about the configuration or the installation process. You could enable a MySQL database, an IDE on the cloud or a runtime environment with a click of the mouse.

For example, I know that with [Codenvy](http://www.cloudbees.com/platform-service-codenvy.cb) you can code, build and debug directly on the cloud. They support some languages, but if you need another one, you should look for another IDE on the cloud. There are some of them.

Nowadays, you can easily store you source code on an online repository and even build and deploy to a runtime instance. So you can have an schema like this one:

Cloud IDE -> Repository -> CI tool -> Runtime environment

You can take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHQcu7Px8Qc) video that I found about a PaaS. It explains the schema above, except for the cloud IDE.

On an IaaS you could have a similar scenario. However, you have to install everything from scratch.

You should try it by yourself and see if it meets your needs or not. For big projects, I would prefer to use Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans,...

Answer (score 0):

You could either consider running an IDE image in the cloud with a VNC connector, or using a pure cloud IDE.  Cloud IDEs show a lot of promise in terms of configuration, performance, and security.  As some additional background, you can read about whether cloud IDEs are the future, and the overall market for cloud IDEs on quora with some good questions asked and answered.

[https://www.quora.com/Do-you-think-that-Web-Based-IDEs-are-the-future-of-IDEs/answer/Tyler-Jewell?**snids**=895306182&**nsrc**=1&**filter**=all](https://www.quora.com/Do-you-think-that-Web-Based-IDEs-are-the-future-of-IDEs/answer/Tyler-Jewell?__snids__=895306182&__nsrc__=1&__filter__=all)

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-market-size-of-cloud-IDEs-and-what-are-the-possible-business-models/answer/Tyler-Jewell

Disclaimer: I am founder of Codenvy a maker of a cloud IDE.